# How to append structure to a table of type ANY

Tags: abap

```
DATA ls TYPE string.
DATA lr_ref TYPE REF TO data.  
FIELD-SYMBOLS <'l_s> TYPE any.  
FIELD-SYMBOLS <'l_t> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.  

ls = 'test'.  
GET REFERENCE OF ls INTO lr_ref.  
ASSIGN lr_ref->* TO <'l_s>.
```

Now how should I append `<'l_s>` to `<'l_t>` ?

Comment: Please give us some background information. What is your target?

Comment: I have a reference (In above example, lr_ref) which can point to a structure or a table. In case its table, I will assign it to field symbol of type table. But in case its a structure, will assign it to field symbol of type any(As done in above example). If, by some way, I can append this structure to a table, then in both the cases (structure/table), I shall have a table of data which I can process thereafter in same piece of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to create data `like` a standard table of `<l_s>` and then assign it to `<l_t>`.

```
create data lr_ref like standard table of <l_s>.
assign lr_ref->* to <l_t>.

append <l_s> to <l_t>.
```

It will work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a misunderstanding with regards to generic types like `ANY`.

`ANY`, `CLIKE` and other generic types are somewhat similar to abstract classes in that they can not be instantiated. You can not declare an actual variable of type `ANY`, which is very sensible when you think about it like this: `DATA foo TYPE i` reserves a four-byte space somewhere in memory for your integer to go, but what should `DATA bar TYPE any` reserve? (Oversimplifying here, but I hope to get the point across.)

You can only use the generic types in parameters, references and field symbols where they can be used to ensure that a certain kind of data object is passed or referred to. You can have you field symbol `TYPE STANDARD TABLE` point to any standard table, but you have to provide that standard table by some other means. And you will have to ensure that the actual - concrete - type is suitable for your needs, i. e. compatible to whatever you wish to append to the table.